# How to Get NGINX API Gateway to request JWT on behalf of a client?

Tags: nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

Scenario:

- I have an NGINX reverse proxy in front of keycloak, acting as an API gateway.
- I want to query for a url via the API gateway, but authenticate against the KC server (via the API gateway as well) using the JWT flow - i.e get a JWT token in response to my authenticated query via the API gateway.
- The JWT should be used by the NGINX API gateway to authorize the client's established session to get the request URL

Questions:

a) How would a curl request for this flow look like ? and

b) How would I configure this in NGINX?

c) What authorization/authentication configuration should be present on the keycloak server?